# push array in array field in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an array called students in a schema called Course. I created a route that allows me to add students to this array using a student's `ObjectID` like so:

```
 router.put('/addStudent/:courseID', function (req, res) {
        Course.findOneAndUpdate({courseID: req.params.courseID}, {$push: {students: req.body.students}})
        .populate('students')
        .exec(function (err, course) {

            if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem adding this information to the database");
            res.status(201).send(course);
        })
    });
```

When I try making a PUT request to my endpoint with the following JSON body:

```
{
    "students":["5b1f06cafa355c2d187c344f"]
}
```

Nothing happens at all, it just sends me back the course with the student ID not added. How do I make it so I could add more student IDs to the array? I don't want it to replace the array with a student ID, I want to keep adding more as I make more requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Put your schema and content in `req.body.students`

Comment: That does not make any sense. Adding one ObjectID is fine, but when I try to add another one, it replaces the first ObjectID with the new one when it should be adding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [$each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) with [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/)

```
Course.findOneAndUpdate(
  { courseID: req.params.courseID },
  { $push: { students: { $each: req.body.students } } }
)
```

---

```
Course.findOneAndUpdate(
  { courseID: req.params.courseID },
  { $addToSet: { students: { $each: req.body.students } } }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

put request will update your db and `findOneAndUpdate` method from mongoose is also for updating you current item, you need to use post request and `save` method in mongoose instead if you want create a new item.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this:

```
Course.findOneAndUpdate(
{ courseID: req.params.courseID }, 
{ $push: {
    students: req.body.students
}}, options, function(err, values){

});
```

Comment: Does not work, just replaces an id in the array if there is one in there instead of adding to it.

Comment: Kindly go through the above edited code. @omar

Comment: Sorry, but I don't seem to understand? The only thing I see difference is the options, but I am not sure what that is? As you can see, my current code does have the $push

Comment: You can try the given below link or use the Emad Dehnavi concept 
http://blog.ocliw.com/2012/11/25/mongoose-add-to-an-existing-array/